# How to search by array field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a document like this:

```
[PUT] /my_index/cars/1

{
    "color" : "red",
    "passengers" : ["John", "Annie", "William"]
}
```

I am trying to search all the cars where "John" is a passenger.

Answer (score 1):

You can search just like any other field.

```
-bash-4.2$ curl 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty=true&q=passengers:John'
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.15342641,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "cars",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.15342641,
      "_source" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "passengers" : [ "John", "Annie", "William" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: and if I want all John's and Annie's?

Comment: just add OR clause `q=passengers:John OR passengers:Annie`

Answer (score 0):

Although codegrep_admin's answer works, I was looking for something I could manipulate easier.

I ended up using the `bool` query like this:

```
[GET] /my_index/cars/_search

{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "match": { "passengers": "John" }},
            { "match": { "passengers": "Annie" }}
      ]
    }
}
```